# Query was empty

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

```
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
$query = mysqli_prepare($con,"insert into tablename (firstName) VALUES (?)");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, 's', $this->firstName);/
        mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
        mysqli_stmt_close($query);
        mysqli_close($con);
```

I am getting error: Query was empty. Although when I was not using prepared statements, it was working.
please help me identify error.

Comment: also this happens only when I am using it in a private function of a class.
if i execute same statements in a new php file, it works

Answer (score -1):

Capitalize INSERT INTO in your statement and bacltick tablename

Comment: Are you using a __construct in your function or cslling it direct from outside code ? If it's a private function then you need a __construct inside the class to call it. Try making the function public and see if it works

Comment: why to capitalize INSERT INTO, is it case sensitive??.. i don't think so, then why did you say that?